# Multiple database support in Java Application

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have a Java Web Application which currently supports DB2 and Oracle as the back-end databases. I am planning to support MySQL also and hence facing this problem.

So far, I've been hard-coding queries inside the code itself and wherever necessary, put an if-else condition for queries which are not same for both Oracle and DB2.

eg. To get first 10 employees with high salaries, I have to code like this

```
String query = null;
if(DatabaseUtil.getDatabaseName().equalsIgnoreCase("oracle"))
{
    query = "select * from ( select * from emp order by sal desc ) where ROWNUM <= 5";
}
else if(DatabaseUtil.getDatabaseName().equalsIgnoreCase("db2"))
{
    query = "select * from emp order by sal desc fetch first 5 rows only";
}
```

If I add Mysql, the if-else condition grows and it gets cluttered.

```
if(DatabaseUtil.getDatabaseName().equalsIgnoreCase("oracle"))
{
    query = "select * from ( select * from emp order by sal desc ) where ROWNUM <= 5";
}
else if(DatabaseUtil.getDatabaseName().equalsIgnoreCase("db2"))
{
    query = "select * from emp order by sal desc fetch first 5 rows only";
}
else if(DatabaseUtil.getDatabaseName().equalsIgnoreCase("mysql"))
{
    query = "select * from emp order by sal desc limit 0,5";
}
```

What do you think is a solution to this. Can Hibernate/JPA can solve this problem?

Things I tried

1) Wrote a factory design pattern to do interface based query selection. Just call Interface.getHighSalEmployees() and it will return me the concrete class implemented queries based on what driver was loaded. That is if the application is connected to Oracle, it will give me OracleConcreteClass.getHighSalEmployees()

2) Read about Hibernate/HQL - but couldn't land on anything plausible.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify what dialect to use when using Hibernate.  You can find list of Hibernate dialects in https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/tree/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect.  For example, there are `Oracle10gDialect`, `H2Dialect`, and `MySQL5Dialect`.

You can also create your own dialect if you want.

Providing you only use HQL or JP QL (and never issue native query directly), you should be able to remove your *if* - *else* conditions.  In the startup of your application, your code need to select the proper JDBC driver and Hibernate dialect when creating the persistence context.

If you use more than one databases in your application, you should be able to create multipe persistence contexts that have different dialects.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, your problem fits perfectly with the idea of having an ORM between your database and your java logic.  The idea would be to build Hibernate (to say an implementation) entities on top of your DB tables, views, etc., and delegate to the ORM the building of the queries, updates, etc. in the specific underlying DB syntax.

When you deploy your application, you should play with its configuration files in order to instantiate the proper JDBC driver and Hibernate configuration, everything in the config files, so you have never to change your logic.  Once you have done this effort, it will be trivial to port your application to any other RDBM you can imagine.